# What should we name our chatroom?

Tags: discussion, chat

The default was **Open Source**, I, on a whim, changed it to **The MIT License**.

Let's let the community decide, how should we name our chatroom?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### The Bikeshed

**This is now the name of the chatroom** - I changed it when it became apparent the voting went in this suggestion's favour.

[Originally proposed](https://opensource.meta.stackexchange.com/a/25/98) by Carpetsmoker (user38) whose account has since been deleted, a 'bikeshed' refers to [Parkinson's Law of Triviality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parkinson's_law_of_triviality). It states that in organising projects, organisers will spend time deciding on insignificant matters such as the colour or material of a bikeshed instead of solving more important matters such as an overall architectural design document.

Comment: Accepted within 20 minutes...

Comment: Btw. Why his account has been deleted? He deleted his own account?

Comment: @kenorb - He contacted the SE team while we were still early private beta and asked for deletion. I can't tell you much more, because I wasn't a mod and didn't have anything to do with it.

Answer (score 18):

**The bikeshed**

In the open source community, a "bikeshed" is a meaningless discussion about something of very little or no importance... It was popularized by phk on a FreeBSD mailing list post (which you can [read here](http://bikeshed.com/)).

Comment: I like it! Another!

Comment: Don't you mean "The Blue Bikeshed"...?

Comment: (not enough rep to add a link) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parkinson%27s_law_of_triviality

Comment: @trichoplax No, I think it should be "The Red Bikeshed".

Comment: @MadaraUchiha Excellent, now comment voting can show which colour is the obvious best choice

Answer (score 12):

### [The Bazaar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Cathedral_and_the_Bazaar)

(thanks E.S.Raymond)

Answer (score 7):

I suggest:

**Free As In Speech**

Answer (score 6):

### [The Off-License](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off_licence)

(pun intended)

Comment: Heh. This seems like it fits well with our site.

Comment: I'm sorry if I'm dense, but I don't get it - are we alcoholics?

Comment: Guys, I'm only 15...

Comment: @Zizouz212 No need to feel self-conscious about it; you are working on a solution to that problem at this very moment.

Answer (score -3):

**Hyde Park** after the well-known [speaker's corner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speakers'_Corner) there.

Answer (score -4):

## FLOSS

- Recommend for [Free and open-source software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_and_open-source_software)
- Stands for **"Free/Libre Open-Source Software"**.(Also visit [FLOSS Concept Booklet](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/FLOSS_Concept_Booklet))
- [Endorsed](http://www.gnu.org/philosophy/floss-and-foss.en.html) by Richard M. Stallman

Answer (score -4):

### Freedom

- [Free Software Is Even More Important Now](http://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-software-even-more-important.html)
- [Free Speech](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gratis_versus_libre)

Inspiration wikis: [Freedom of information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freedom_of_information), [Freedom of speech](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freedom_of_speech), [The Philosophy of Freedom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Philosophy_of_Freedom),

Answer (score -5):

I nominate **The Question Tracker**

Answer (score -8):

## License to Chill

(The real question is, is this a James Bond joke or a Beastie Boys joke?)

Comment: The real answer is "*dad pls stop*"

Answer (score -14):

Keep **The MIT License** as it is.

Comment: Hint: get the Peer Pressure badge. :)

Comment: @VictorStafusa People pay attention to meta badges?