# What's our not-so-secret blurb?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion, sharing

Now that we're growing really big, getting lots of questions, and plenty of really amazing active users, we should start spreading the word!

From [7 Essential Meta Questions of Every Beta](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/the-7-essential-meta-questions-of-every-beta/):

> Imagine you’ve just gotten on an elevator with a friendly stranger. You have precisely one floor to describe your community to them. What would you say? The elevator pitch is a brief sentence that describes what your site is about. Every word counts!
>
> Once decided, it can be sliced and diced to form:
>
> - the tagline
> - the motto
> - the blurb under the logo
> - a convenience redirect “nickname” for the site
> - perhaps eventually the domain name in some form
>
> (Due to a variety of practical difficulties with domain names, we prefer to de-emphasize domain name selection. Most sites will retain their topic.stackexchange.com names indefinitely.)
>
> Naming is hard — really hard. But if you can come up with a sensible elevator pitch for your community, it’s a great starting point.

P.S. Whoever thought of [The Bikeshed](https://opensource.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20/what-should-we-name-our-chatroom/25#25) for our chatroom better get over here this instant and start raising ideas! >:D

Answer (score 3):

We're some awesome people who try to help each other change the world through altruism shown through the freedom in our products. :P

P.S. I think `oss.se` is a better shorthand than `os.se` because OS sounds like Operating Systems, while OSS is concisely Open Source Software. An abundant `S` is a blessing for the site not to come with pluralization bugs.

Comment: some of us are not awesome you insensitive clod! Try to be a little more inclusive.

Comment: This site is not solely about open source software. We can't use “software” in the site name or other short description.